# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields Pro como ativar Google Maps

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, plugin-wordpress

estou utilizando o plugin "Advanced Custom Fields Pro" do wordpress.
Estou tentando utilizar o Campo customizado do Wordpress, porem o mesmo pede a key para o acesso da API do Google, eu ja tenho a key mais não sei onde devo colocar para poder utilizar o mapa! 
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar o seguinte código abaixo no arquivo **functions.php** do seu tema:

```
function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){
    $api['key'] = 'xxx'; // Sua key
    return $api;
}
add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');
```

[Mais informações](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/)